# Disk-based trie?

Tags: data-structures, trie, memory-optimization

I'm trying to build a **[Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) but on a mobile phone** which has very limited memory capacity.

I figured that it is probably best that the whole structure be stored on disk, and only loaded as necessary since I can tolerate a few disk reads. But, after a few attempts, it seems like this is a very complicated thing to do.

What are some ways to store a Trie on disk (i.e. only partially loaded) and keep the fast lookup property?
Is this even a good idea to begin with?

Comment: I'd reach for a B-tree rather than a trie in this situation, but I'd love to know the answer to this question too.

Comment: Tries are structures to support fast look-up. This looks like good use-case for some embedded database engine, like SQLite, or some http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm derivative

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The paper [B-tries for disk-based string management](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/jzobel/fulltext/vldbj09.pdf) answers your question.

It makes the observation:

> To our knowledge, there has yet to be a proposal in literature for a
> trie-based data structure, such as the burst trie, the can reside
> efficiently on disk to support common string processing tasks.

Comment: Link to naskitis.com seems to be down again (or something entirely else), new URL for the paper: https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/jzobel/fulltext/vldbj09.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I've only glanced at it briefly, but [Shang's "Trie methods for text and spatial data on secondary storage"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.64.4843) discusses paged trie representations, and might be a useful starting point.